# Need to evaluate difference regardless of time Interval change on Grafana

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana

My Prometheus is exposing currently 30s time interval data.

**Base PromQL:**
`local_cache_miss{kind="something"}`

**Calculative PromQL:**
`max_over_time(local_cache_miss{kind="$interfaceKey"} [1m]) - min_over_time(local_cache_miss{kind="$interfaceKey"} [1m])`

Where Min time interval = 30s

It works perfectly fine for me.

[image: expected output]

When I choose 1m or large time interval.
I started to get some data which I don't expect.

[image: unexpected result]

Here something I need as the difference was,

**Target formula:** The difference between the cache miss values between two adjacent rows.

> 1188745 - 1188671 = 74 (difference column on the second row)
>
> 1188784 - 1188745 = 39 (difference column on the first row)

Based on the proposition of using function **rate** or **increase** I find a slight variation in the count when I'm using intervals higher than the **30s**. Is there any way to align the **[1m]** with the Grafana interval?

Using function **rate** or **increase**,

> 1188784 - 1188745 = 39, but it returns 38.
>
> 1188745 - 1188671 = 74, but it returns 76.

[image: use of rate and increase]

Even though I choose **15s** as "Min time intervale" when I select a duration of **12 hours**, the "Min time intervale" internally turned into **30s**, The same way when I select the duration **24 hours** or more the "Min time intervale" internally turned into **1m**.

I know there is a variable to keep track **[$__interval]** but not sure how should I use it with the accurate count returns.

I'm looking for a suggestion to write the respective PromQL to get the difference.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to do is calculate how many cach misses happened within some time. Prometheus provides to methods:

a) `rate(local_cache_miss{kind="$interfaceKey"} [1m])` calculates the rate per second, this counter counts up.

b) `increase(local_cache_miss{kind="$interfaceKey"} [1m])` calculates the absolute increase of a counter within that timeframe.

both do more or less the same thing (in fact if you do something like `rate(local_cache_miss{kind="$interfaceKey"} [1m]) * 60)` you should get the same number then `increase(local_cache_miss{kind="$interfaceKey"} [1m])`. Both methods recognize when the counter is reset (e.g. when the application restarts and can give you the correct result even though the absolute number decreased (your approach would return the wrong results).

Comment: I'm still facing some differences in the count based on your proposed formula is there any way to get the accurate difference? I have updated my base question part based on your suggestion. Thank you Baitinger for the eager suggestion.

Comment: The derivated metrics are never perfectly absolute, but good enough to see trends that you want to see (like is the cache hit rate going up or down over the time  etc. One thing you might want to take into consideration is the relation of cache misses to cache queries miss/(miss+hit). This percentage as a value you want to have monitor.